# My email is gone and my daughters is there instead

Tags: email

My daughter used my phone for a day and now her email address is on my phone and mine has vanished. How do I get mine back?

Comment: Nicole, I hope the answer I submitted is useful. If so would you kindly select it as answer?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you're using an iPhone.

1. First go into Settings, scroll down and you should see "Mail, Contacts, Calendars". Tap on this item and you will see all the accounts that has been added to the phone.
2. From there you can go to your daughter's account, disable her email, and go to your account and enable your email. That should solve the problem.

Here's a screenshot of the Mail item.

[image]